# Breaking PHP array into equal columns with remainders in earlier rows

Tags: php

I've been trying to figure out how to take an array of items and divide it into 4 html lists (that's my specific need but divide by X would be better), with the extra requirement that any remainders be added from the front.

This is *different* to `array_chunk()` which will do the following:

```
item 1    item 4    item 7    item10
item 2    item 5    item 8
item 3    item 6    item 9
```

Where in fact what I need is this:

```
item 1    item 4    item 7    item 9    
item 2    item 5    item 8    item 10
item 3    item 6
```

With `array_chunk()` I can get the first output with something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13470675/1466282) but `array_chunk()` takes a number of items per chunk as an argument and just leaves the last chunk shorter than the rest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split array into a specific number of chuncks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723059/split-array-into-a-specific-number-of-chuncks), not sure, but I think it will help you?!

Comment: What if you have 9 or 11 elements instead of 10? Use loop and count reminder, do some algorithm for that.

Comment: The answer lies in [this answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15723262/1466282). Thank you everyone for the responses.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$item_arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

$col_cnt = 4;

$item_cnt = count($item_arr);
$row_cnt = ceil($item_cnt/$col_cnt);
$item_in_last_row = $item_cnt%$col_cnt;
$temp_cnt = $row_cnt-1;
$curr_cnt = $row_cnt;

$curr_item = 0;
for($i=0;$i<$row_cnt;$i++){
    $curr_cnt = $row_cnt;
    for($j=$i,$x=0,$k=1;$x<$col_cnt;$x++,$j+=$curr_cnt){
        if($curr_item == $item_cnt){
            break;
        }
        if($k > $item_in_last_row && $item_in_last_row != 0){
            $abc = $curr_cnt;
            $curr_cnt = $temp_cnt;
            $temp_cnt = $abc;
        }
        print $item_arr[$j]." ";
        $k++;
        $curr_item++;
    }
    print "<br>";
} 
?>

Output:

1 4 7 9
2 5 8 10
3 6
```